# Initial query resent the data when client got reconnect

Tags: ignite

I tried to use contentious query to monitor a cache and set initial query, LocalListener and RemoteFilter as example did.

The issue I met is when client reconnect to Ignite cluster, the initial query will query the data from cache which the client might already got before.

I tried to use unchanged ID or instance name

```
cfg.setConsistentId("de01");
cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("test1");
```

but does not work.

**Is any way to solve this issue?**

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

On disconnect phase of reconnect server closes query listener and loses information which updates were already sent to client. The only way not to miss some updates in that situation - run initial query again.

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin. The doc said the node has an update queue which has the information which record had been sent. In this case if the client come back with an unique ID, the node should know which record has been sent and which were not.

Comment: When server closes query listener, it loses information about that client. It happens because server can't keep updates for disconnected client for infinite time (it doesn't know if that client connects again or not). So, unique Id doesn't work in that case.